# Calling NumField on Value panics in some cases (go)

Tags: go, reflection

I'm using reflect.ValueOf(..) to loop through elements in a struct. I noticed that calling NumField fails if i pass the struct vs. pointer to the struct in the ValueOf function.

```
v = reflect.ValueOf(user)
v.NumField() // panics
```

Vs.

```
v = reflect.ValueOf(*user)
v.NumField() // works
```

Is there a way to find out beforehand if v would panic, before calling NumField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [reflect.Indirect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Indirect) to handle both cases in the question:

```
v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(x))
v.NumField()
```

The [NumField](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.NumField) documentation says:

> It panics if v's Kind is not Struct.

Check the kind to avoid the panic:

```
if v.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
   v.NumField()
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the ‘Kind’ to ensure it’s a structure.